# why is my insert not inserting a record in database

Tags: asp.net, sql, ado.net

I am trying to insert a record into the database using the below method.  I am calling this method in a button click event but for some reasons no record is being inserted.

There are four fields which need to be inserted: rpttemplateid - I am getting that field from another database table and all the other feilds are just static values.

What am i doing wrong below?

```
public void updatereporttemplate()
{
    string cnn = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Underwriting"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection cnn1 = new SqlConnection(cnn);
    cnn1.Open();
    string getrptdesc = "select max(rptdesc) + 1 from report_description where rptdesc < 999 and rptdesc is not null";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(getrptdesc, cnn1);
    SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    sdr.Read();

    int getcount = int.Parse(sdr[0].ToString());
    sdr.Close();
    string commandtext1 = "INSERT INTO report_template" + "(rpttemplateid,rpttemplatedescr,minsubs,minmebers) " +
          " Values( " + getcount  + "," + "  " + " ,  " +  0  + "," + 0  + ")";
    SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand
    {
        CommandText = commandtext1,
        Connection = cnn1

    };
```

Comment: Where are you executing the INSERT query string?

Comment: Iam executing the insert in a button clcick event

Comment: No, but you need to call an execute() on the command1 object right? Else how will command1 insert?

Comment: where you are excuting the commandtext1

Comment: @vamsikirankolla, an important but unrelated to this, "never trust a developer who writes inline parameters". Jon Skeet uses SQL/DB parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open the connection

```
cnn1.Open();
```

And then execute the command

```
command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near ','.

Source Error: 


Line 145:
Line 146:        SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(commandtext1,cnn2);
Line 147:        command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
Line 148:        cnn2.Close();
Line 149:

Comment: That is a sql error. You did not provide the command with the fieldname for the 2nd column. You have

" + getcount  + "," + "  " + " ,  " +  0  + "," + 0  + ")";

Do you see the "  " after the first comma? Your DB is expecting a fieldname or value there. If you do not have a value to put there, change this to

" + getcount  + "," + 0  + "," + 0  + ")";

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `command1.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Also, have you considered using an IDENTITY column in your table instead of trying to manually set the count? What if that page is hit by multiple people at the same time?

Comment: make sure your connection is open

Comment: Your insert statement may be missing something: try putting in "''" for that 2nd value. that is quote + single quote + single quote + quote

Comment: " Values( " + getcount  + "," + " '' " + " ,  " +  0  + "," + 0  + ")";

Comment: SqlConnection cnn2 = new SqlConnection(cnn);
        cnn2.Open();
        string commandtext1 = "INSERT INTO report_template" + "(rpttemplateid,rpttemplatedescr,minsubs,minmebers) " +
         " Values( " + getcount + "," + " ''  " + " ,  " + 0 + "," + 0 + ")";

        SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(commandtext1,cnn2);
        command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cnn2.Close();